# Sleep the thread on if statement check, Python Pool

Tags: python, sleep, pool

I have a code the reads a very large text file and process each line in Pools.

In the case of the **elif** I need to sleep the whole process for 120 seconds, in other words, I want all other Pools created to pause. But after 120 seconds all Pools should resume working.

The code's functionality is similar to this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import sys

sys.tracebacklimit = 0

def req(line):

    if "@" not in line:
        # (some function for processing here)
        return line
    elif "somestring" in line:
        #HERE I NEED TO SLEEP ALL POOLS
    else:
        # (some function for processing)
        return line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(20)
    with open("list.txt") as source_file:
        # chunk the work into batches of 20 lines at a time
        pool.map(req, source_file, 35)
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. Please fix it. Python is very space sensitive and what you show simply won't run.

Comment: You're trying to pause all the worker threads, not the pools. There is only one pool.

Comment: I understand that, the code works fine but when I pasted it here the spaces were removed.

Comment: Not all the scheduled workers are running at once, so pausing the running threads is non trivial.

Comment: That's fine. Fix the spaces here so I understand what you have.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry I'm a bit new to python, how is it possible to pause all workers then?

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool` doesn't have a method to pause or sleep the pool. If you don't care about Windows, you _could_ get all the `Process`es in the pool, get the `_popen` object or the PID for each process, and send them all a `SIGSTOP` signal. But this is probably not the best way to go.

Comment: @abarnert Is there any better way than multiprocessing.Pool to read a big file with high efficiency and use sleep to deal with pausing threads on certain conditions?

Comment: A probably better solution is to use a sync object, like an `Event`, that every task `wait`s on at the start (or, if they're doing a bunch of work, maybe each time through a loop). Then, to pause everything, you just clear the event, and set an alarm to set the event in 120 seconds. (If you want to be able to do recursive pausing, to detect whether everyone has reached the event and blocked, etc., you'll want something more complicated than an `Event`.)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Why do you _want_ to pause the whole pool?

Comment: @abarnert Maybe he wants to implement an anti-spam service, and prevent rude language. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is said by [@abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert), you should use an `Event` object as followed:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import sys
from threading import Event, Timer

sys.tracebacklimit = 0

# Setup clojure environment
def reqgen():
    ev_stop = Event()

    def req(line):

        # Wait at the start
        if ev_stop.is_set():
            ev_stop.wait()

        if "somestring" in line:
            #HERE I NEED TO SLEEP ALL POOLS

            # Clear the internal flag, make all workers await
            ev_stop.clear()

            # An alarm to reset the internal flag,
            # which will make all workers get back to work
            Timer(120, lambda: ev_stop.set()).start()

            # Regular work
            return req(line)

        else:
            # (some function for processing)
            return line

    return req

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(20)
    with open("list.txt") as source_file:
        # chunk the work into batches of 20 lines at a time
        pool.map(reqgen(), source_file, 35)
```